# Node.js classes as modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make my application more object orientated. for this i want to create the following class (object):

in the file Media.js

```
    //Media object
var Media = function (file, targetDirectory) {
    this.file = file;
    this.targetDir = targetDirectory;
    this.fileName = this.getName();
};

Media.prototype.isVideo = function () {
    return this.file.mimetype.indexOf('video') >= 0;
};
Media.prototype.isAudio = function () {
    return this.file.mimetype.indexOf('audio') >= 0;
};
Media.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.file.originalname.substr(0, this.file.originalname.indexOf('.'))
};
```

I wish to use this object in serveral places of my application however im not quite sure how to include it. Also is this a good idea or should i use `Modules` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export your Media object as follows in Media.js

```
module.exports = Media;
```

then simply require Media.js when you need it

```
const Media = require('pathtofile/Media.js')

Media.isAudio(a, b);
```

Comment: Is it possible to instantiate the object ? like above so i pass the parameters